# Email django from using EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: python, django, email, html-email, mailing

I'm trying to send a mail using Django with **EmailMultiAlternatives**. It works well but in "from" says "info"

Is it posible to say my name for example? How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
subject, from_email, to = 'Afiliations', 'info@domain.com', 'other@domain.com'
text_content = 'Afiliation is working.'
t = loader.get_template('emails/afiliados.html')
c = Context({ 'order': order_obj })
html_content = t.render(c)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Comment: You want to display custom name in email inbox?

Comment: Why not change name from your domain?

Comment: I think it is taking the username part of the email. Try this: `"<info@domain.com> info@domain.com"`

Comment: If I change the domain for this: myname@domain.com then the "from" will be "myname" but not capitalized. I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @karthikr, this works: "Name <info@domain.com>". If you want to answer I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the `Name` to be displayed instead of the username part of the email, just do

```
from_email = "info@domain.com <info@domain.com>"
```

OR

```
from_email = "Name <info@domain.com>"
```